# go-pg UnionAll - limit whole expression

Tags: postgresql, go, go-pg

I am trying to use `.UnionAll` method in [go-pg](https://github.com/go-pg/pg/tree/v9) library for golang.

```golang
    var model []Customer
    q0 := db.Model(&model).Where("name = ?", name0).Limit(4)
    q1 := db.Model(&model).Where("name = ?", name1).Limit(3)
    var result []Customer
    if err := q0.UnionAll(q1).Limit(1).Select(&result); !as.NoError(err) {
        return
    }
```

This code produces the query:

```sql
(SELECT "customer"."id", "customer"."name" FROM customers AS "customer" WHERE (name = 'customer 1deificatory zonoid reprepare alacrify serenissime') 
LIMIT 1) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT "customer"."id", "customer"."name" FROM customers AS "customer" WHERE (name = 'customer 2fordless ferroboron radiability dandizette smutch'
LIMIT 3)
)
```

But I expect it to be:

```sql
(SELECT "customer"."id", "customer"."name" FROM customers AS "customer" WHERE (name = 'customer 1deificatory zonoid reprepare alacrify serenissime') 
LIMIT 4) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT "customer"."id", "customer"."name" FROM customers AS "customer" WHERE (name = 'customer 2fordless ferroboron radiability dandizette smutch')
LIMIT 3)

LIMIT 1
```

So how to use go-pg to get raw SQL query which I expect?
The thing is I can't apply the `Limit 1` expression to the whole query for some reason.
Also, my `Limit 4` is not applied correctly to the first `union all` member.
My whole code is [here](https://github.com/ypapax/go-pg-unionall/blob/master/main_test.go#L94).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this query does the trick for you.

```
if err := db.Model().With("union_q", q0.UnionAll(q1)).Table("union_q").Limit(1).Select(&result); !as.NoError(err) {
    return
}
```

The query isn't exactly what you wanted to be and as far as I know, the current version of go-pg can't generate that query. But this query does exactly what you wanted.